# how to update the textview variable for every 5 seconds

Tags: java, android, for-loop, textview, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Updating TextView every N seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776514/updating-textview-every-n-seconds)

Here, I want to update the Hr value in the textview once it is calculated for every iteration, but with a delay of 2 seconds each time. I dont know how to do it. What i get now in the textview is the last value of the iteration. I want all the values to be displayed at a constant delay. anyone help pls.

```
    for(int y=1;y<p.length;y++)
    {
       if(p[y]!=0)
        {
        r=p[y]-p[y-1];
          double x= r/500;
          Hr=(int) (60/x);
          Thread.sleep(2000);
         settext(string.valueof(Hr));
      }
    }
```

Comment: you can use countdowntimer.

Comment: or use `postDelayed` in a for loop

Answer (score 4):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
protected static final long TIME_DELAY = 5000;
//the default update interval for your text, this is in your hand , just run this sample
TextView mTextView;
Handler handler=new Handler();  
int count =0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
    handler.post(updateTextRunnable);
}


Runnable updateTextRunnable=new Runnable(){  
  public void run() {  
      count++;
      mTextView.setText("getting called " +count);
      handler.postDelayed(this, TIME_DELAY);  
     }  
 };  
}
```

I hoped this time you will get into the code and run it .

Comment: where does the TIME_DELAY changes?

Comment: it's upto you can define the initial offset then it will update your textview  after this amount of delay . Suppose u give TIME_DELAY =5000 then your text will update after every 5 sec . u just need to change u r test in  mTextView.setText("your updated text goes here" );

Comment: I dont get it. where should i alter the delay value? pls help

Comment: you do not need to alter the Runnable will be get called every 5 sec interval .

Answer (score 2):

you should use timer class....

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {


        }, 900 * 1000, 900 * 1000);
```

Above code is for every 15 minutes.change this value and use in your case.....

Comment: we need to use runOnUiThread() method for updating TextView from TimerTask Thread

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im new to android. I tried this. but, its not working. where am i doing wrong? pls help.                        for(int y=1;y<p.length;y++)
    {
       if(p[y]!=0)
        {
        r=p[y]-p[y-1];
          double x= r/500;
          Hr=(int) (60/x);
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        public void run() {

           settext(string.valueof(Hr));
        }, 9 * 1000, 9 * 1000);
         
      }
    }

Comment: you should write 300 instead of 9 for every 5minutes update...cheers

Comment: my app gets force closed. so, is the way i have tried is right? and i want the delay for only 5 seconds, how should i do that

Comment: Parameters
task-->the task to schedule.
delay-->amount of time in milliseconds before first execution.
period-->amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent executions.so you should write in delay time and period 5*1000 for 5 second

Answer (score 2):

use `Handler` or `TimerTask(with runOnUiThread())` instead of for loop for updating text after every 5 seconds as :

```
Handler handler=new Handler();  

handler.post(runnable);  
Runnable runnable=new Runnable(){  
  @Override  
    public void run() {  
      settext(string.valueof(Hr));  //<<< update textveiw here
      handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);  
     }  
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

[TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) is just what you need.

Comment: can you pls give me an example for that?

Answer (score 0):

lets us just hope it helps you sufficiently

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
public class demo 
{
  Toolkit toolkit;
  Timer timer;
  public demo()
  {
    toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new scheduleDailyTask(), 0, //initial delay
        2 * 1000); //subsequent rate
  }
  class scheduleDailyTask extends TimerTask 
  {
    public void run() 
    {
      System.out.println("this thread runs for every two second");
      System.out.println("you can call this thread to start in your activity");
      System.out.println("I have used a main method to show demo");
      System.out.println("but you should set the text field values here to be updated simultaneouly");
    }
  }
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    new demo();
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this.. It works perfectly as java app. But, in my app i get the error in toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); when i call the class from my main activity. and my chart activity also gets affected. Is there any way to do this in background asynchronously?

Comment: refer http://eliasbland.wordpress.com/2011/03/11/an-example-of-how-to-run-a-background-task-and-report-progress-in-the-status-bar-using-asynctask-on-android/ , this is using the background task , it is not exactly what you need but will get you started , keep me posted for any further help