# Adding a time from timepicker in current time in android

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I want to add the time in hours or minutes chosen from time picker in the current time displayed in text box .. how can we update the time and date also get changed according to the time..
Tell me how can i add the time from time picker and add in current time and date automatically gets changed..

The below is the code of TimePicker...

```
 private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =
    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener  (){
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            pHour = hourOfDay;
           pMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay();
            displayToast();
        }
    };

/** Updates the time in the TextView */
private void updateDisplay() {
   displayTime.setText(
        new StringBuilder()
                .append(pad(pHour)).append(":")
                .append(pad(pMinute)));
 tv.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mDay).append("-")
            .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")

            .append(mYear).append(" "));
   // tv.setText(mydate);

}

/** Displays a notification when the time is updated */
private void displayToast() {
    Toast.makeText(this, new StringBuilder().append("Time choosen is ").append(displayTime.getText()),   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

/** Add padding to numbers less than ten */
private static String pad(int c) {
    if (c >= 10)
        return String.valueOf(c);
    else
        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);
}

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    /** Capture our View elements */
    displayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);
    pickTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickTime);


    buttonStartTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartTime);
    buttonStopTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopTime);
    displayTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeDisplay);

    buttonStartTime.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonStopTime.setOnClickListener(this);


    /** Listener for click event of the button */
    pickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    /** Get the current time */
     tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    pHour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    pMinute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


    //mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    /** Display the current time in the TextView */
    updateDisplay();
}

private String TimePickerDialog(MainActivity mainActivity,
        OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener2, int pHour2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnStartTime) {
       // textViewShowTime.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(),
             //   R.style.normalText);
        setTimer();
        buttonStopTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonStartTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
       //edtTimerValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //edtTimerValue.setText("");
        startTimer();

    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnStopTime) {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        buttonStartTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        buttonStopTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }
}

private void setTimer() {
    int times = 0;
   /* if (!displayTime.getText().toString().equals("")) {
       times = Integer.parseInt(displayTime.getText().toString());
        //time=timer;
    } else
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Minutes...",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
    times = pHour*60 + pMinute;

   totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 60 * times * 1000;

    //timeBlinkInMilliseconds = 30 * 1000;
}


private void startTimer() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {
        // 500 means, onTick function will be called at every 500
        // milliseconds

        @Override
        public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
            long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;



            displayTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", seconds / 3600,
                    (seconds % 3600) / 60, (seconds % 60)));
            // format the textview to show the easily readable format

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // this function will be called when the timecount is finished
            displayTime.setText("Time up!");
            displayTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonStartTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonStopTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            //edtTimerValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    }.start();

}

/** Create a new dialog for time picker */

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                mTimeSetListener, pHour, pMinute,true);
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476476/how-to-update-the-textview-variable-for-every-5-seconds which update time every 5 sec.

Comment: Thanks..But i have to select the value from time picker and at run time....